# Is is possible to simultaneously use Arduino serial monitor while receiving data from Processing?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, communication, processing, simultaneous

I am attempting to send some data from [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) to my Arduino over the serial connection so that the Arduino can control an LED strip. Could I view the serial monitor while this transfer was taking place?

It is irking me that I cannot use any `Serial.println` statements (for debugging) while Processing is communicating with the Arduino. Everytime I try I get

> Serial port 'COM3' already in use. Try quitting any programs that may be using it.

Is there a way for this serial communication to take place while I view the serial monitor at the same time?

Comment: Can't you use Processing console to look at this data? With println()

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the error message mentions COM3 suggests you are running on Windows. Unfortunately Windows doesn't allow multiple processes to simultaneously connect to the same serial port. This is different from Unix-based systems which do allow simultaneous serial port connections.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Linux host, I have used a Python script send commands whilst monitoring results on the serial monitor.  I seem to recall I had to open the serial monitor first and then run the other program.

Unfortunately, I can't help you with how to achieve that in Processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) that will allow you to monitor the serial communications on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 Serial communication,
Imagine you have already given USB as COM3 have a bluetooth device connected to your arduino Tx & Rx port, Let that be COM8. Now view COM3 in Arduino and COM8 in Processing.I could do this.